# How to unwrap lines in TextMate?

Tags: textmate, word-wrap

I love pressing ^q to wrap a line (add newlines).
I want to be able to highlight these multiple lines and press a keyboard shortcut to unwrap them (delete newlines).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

⌃⌥Q (ctrl + alt + Q) should do what you want.

Comment: Yes, it does! Thank you! :) Where did you find that? Is there an official reference for Textmate keyboard shortcuts?